# iTextSharp with MVC View, put paragraphs side by side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, itext

When creating a `View` for iTextSharp, can I put two paragraphs next to each other?
Such as, in my `View` I have two paragraphs like this -

```
<paragraph>
    <chunk>Some Text 1</chunk><newline />
    <chunk>Some Text 2</chunk><newline />
</paragraph>

<paragraph>
    <chunk>Some Text 3</chunk><newline />
    <chunk>Some Text 4</chunk><newline />
</paragraph>
```

Is there a way to display these paragraphs next to each other in the PDF? If so, how can I add as much space as I like between them? (I am using Razor syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a table with three columns for this. The center column will just be empty but you can set its width to give you whatever spacing you want. I know the current HTML trend is to avoid tables but this is a really good case for when you should use them.

Comment: Thanks Chris! 
Do you recommend putting the paragraph itself in the table, or get rid of the paragraph tags all together?

Comment: I don't think there would any advantage to using paragraph tags but I also don't think they'd hurt you either. I guess knowing that I'd go without them for starters just to avoid any possible extra code cruft.